# Satellites in orbit which transmit data available to public?

Tags: artificial-satellite, data-transmission, noaa

There are websites that present home projects where people have successfully received weather satellite imagery from NOAA satellites (such as [this one](http://www.asciimation.co.nz/bb/2014/03/19/using-rtl-sdr-to-automatically-receive-weather-satellite-images)).

I would like to know if there are other satellites in orbit, which transmit data in a form that can be (with proper setup of course) received by enthusiasts? It doesn't need to be imagery only, it can be any kind of data that is generated by the craft.

As a plus, a particularly nice thing to have would be a website with a (updated) list of such satellites in orbit.

**Edit:** 
My question can be considered a generalisation of an [existing one](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/4485/which-high-resolution-earth-facing-satellites-transmit-data-to-the-public-in-rea). I am asking for any data, not only imagery. And it doesn't need to be "simply" decodable by means of general consumer products.

Comment: Does 'satellite TV' count?

Comment: @AndrewThompson Expecting such answer I added "generated by the craft" in the question :) Perhaps it didn't state my intention clearly.

Comment: This is a list type question, which are generally frowned upon across the stack exchange network. It is however an interesting list type question. A community wiki answer might be suit this question nicely.

Comment: ...starting with the ISS HAM radio :)

Comment: Look into AmSat.

Comment: All NASA Heliophysics data must be made public, much of which can be found at [CDAWeb](http://cdaweb.gsfc.nasa.gov).  I think the planetary division has slightly different rules, but those can be found at [NSSDCA](http://nssdc.gsfc.nasa.gov/planetary/).  I am not sure about Earth Science or Astrophysics, but I am sure they have data available somewhere...

Comment: You can look at the [NASA Eyes application](https://eyes.nasa.gov/).  It shows a great wealth of information about various missions, including surface data sent back from orbiters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though there are other types of satellites which fit your question, I wanted to point our that there are publicly usable amateur radio satellites.

Below quoted from wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amateur_radio_satellite)

> These satellites can be used for free by licensed amateur radio operators for voice (FM, SSB) and data communications (AX.25, packet radio, APRS). Currently, over 5 fully operational amateur-satellites in orbit act as repeaters, linear transponders or store and forward digital relays.

It would be possible to listen in on others communications with these satellites, while they were in range, and the type of data could be voice, Morse code, or any of a number of kinds of digital packet data.

A site which tracks these satellites:
http://www.n2yo.com/satellites/?c=18

Answer (score 0):

I agree with one of the comments above that this is more of a list question, so it's hard to get a definitive answer.  That being said, the source that I personally am most familiar with is [USGS Earth Explorer](http://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/).  Mainly geographic data.

Comment: I did a brief search and couldn't find how to receive the satellite data, could you point me to that maybe? But I see there is an online interface to acquire it.